# Get values in Python dictionary from list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2 , 'c': 3}
```

with `d['a']` or `d.get('a')` I get `1`.

How can I get the values in the dictionary from a list of keys?

Something like

```
d[['a','b']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2 , 'c': 3}
>>> [d[k] for k in ['a','b']]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> map(d.get, ['a','b'])
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to a list in this case you could use a string. Like so:

`map({'a':1, 'b':2 , 'c': 3}.get,"abc")`

Comment: What if the dict had a key "bc"? This will only work if the dict has single character keys.